# Flutter Scale Animation for the center of the photo

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to scale rectangle photo or icon. I am creating svg-png-icon type photo but i couldn't scale for only middle of the photo. For example;

When i will change the x variable (width of middle) only middle will change. Its such as linear animation.

Please check images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0bf8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8JvX.png)

Comment: In an AnimatedBuilder use AspectRatio.

Comment: sorry, i didn't find solution with AspectRatio.